# Flutter : How to develop widgets on scaffold that have background image and safeArea?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout

[Screen That I want to develop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhvbz.png)

I'm new in Flutter Basically, I want to add these images on a top-off background like boxes is there any way to do this and screen be responsive on multiple devices this is what I start to do but it seems to be complex for me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.75), BlendMode.darken),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/72.png",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea how you can achieve in your design:

for the boxes, you need to use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
)
```

your structure can be:

```
      Scaffold
        SafeArea
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.75), BlendMode.darken),
              ),
            ),
            child: StaggeredGridView
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Stack

  - Scaffold

    - body

      - StaggeredGridView
      - Custom bottom navigation bar
  - Image

Wrap your `Scaffold` Inside stack, why ? because by default `Scaffold` using SafeArea, and you didn't need safe area for the background, you only need `SafeArea` for the `AppBar`, `Menu`, And `CustomButtomNav` only (referring to picture)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.75), BlendMode.darken,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children:[
              StaggeredGridView(
              /// Put your staggered view here
              ),
              CustomBottomNav(
              /// Put your custom bottom here
              ),
            ]
          )
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am not gonna deep into staggered & custom bottom nav, btw this is some advice. There is a design UI & UX Guideline, i highly recommend you to follow these guideline, so you don't have to do some research and testing for the UI Component while developing it in flutter, unless you have large team.
check it here : (https://material.io/develop/flutter)